# XML XPATH : how to get attribute values of a node and all its child nodes in XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<Roottag>
<ParentTag isAP="false">
        <Name>Safari Packages</Name>
        <Description>parent tag desc</Description>
        <Number>abc 1234567</Number>
        <Price>78</Price>
        <OfferVal code="XYZ">
            <Value>false</Value>
        </OfferVal>
<ChildTag isCA="false"  id="ABCD">
<Name>Safari Package</Name>
            <Description>Safari Package Summar 2018</Description>
            <Number/>
            <Animal ishealthy="true" id="Tiger123">
                <Name>My Tiger</Name>
                <Description>Bengal Tiger</Description>
                <weight>150.0</weight>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="EC">
                <Value>false</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="BD">
                <Value>true</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
            </Animal>
            <Animal ishealthy="true" id="Lion456">
                <Name>My Lion</Name>
                <Description>African Lion</Description>
                <weight>195.0</weight>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="EC">
                <Value>true</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="BD">
                <Value>false</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
            </Animal>
</ChildTag>
<ChildTag isCA="false"  id="ABCD">
<Name>Back Door Feeding Package</Name>
            <Description>Safari Package Summar 2018</Description>
            <Number/>
            <Animal ishealthy="true" id="Tiger123">
                <Name>My Tiger</Name>
                <Description>Bengal Tiger</Description>
                <weight>150.0</weight>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="EC">
                <Value>false</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="BD">
                <Value>true</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
            </Animal>
            <Animal ishealthy="true" id="Lion456">
                <Name>My Lion</Name>
                <Description>African Lion</Description>
                <weight>195.0</weight>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="EC">
                <Value>true</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
                <DisplayVal avaliable="BD">
                <Value>false</Value>
                </DisplayVal>
            </Animal>
</ChildTag>
</ParentTag>
<Roottag>
```

Here I need to get `<ChildTag>` with `<Name>Safari Package</Name>`  and any `<Animal>` whose  `<Displayval>` 's `<value>` is *true*  once this condition is passed I need all the child nodes of `<Animal>` and its attributes with animals id .
I tried below XPATH , I am getting all child nodes under matching `<Animal>`. in this case Lion. however I am not getting *id* and *ishealthy* attributes of that `<Animal>`.

XPATH I tried in java..

```
final XPathExpression expr = prepareXpathContext()
                .compile(/Roottag/ParentTag/ChildTag[Name='Safari Package']/Animal[DisplayVal[@avaliable='EC']/Value='true']/*");
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exact XML nodes that you would like to select from your XML using XPath.   Keep in mind that XPath is for selection, and XSLT is for transformation.  You cannot select an arbitrary arrangement of nodes via XPath alone.

Comment: You want `/@*` instead of `/*`. `/@*` says "get child attributes", while `/*` says "get child elements". If you want both, use `/node()`.

Comment: i have updated my Question with tags .

Comment: thanks Welbog, i will try that